# Reading values both from QueryString and Hash?

Tags: javascript, query-string

There's a lof of js code to read query strings.

However after I saw the reply from `facebook login` Which is something like

`http://localhost:55643/WebSite2/HTMLPage2.htm#access_token=CAACSIC6Koe......roHXCK8ZD&expires_in=5439`

I said to myself that I must write some code to handle values after the hash (`#`).

And so I did :

```
(function ($)
    {
        $.getQs = function (specificUrl)
        {
            var st = specificUrl || window.location.href;
            var o = {}, e;
            var re = /([^#?&=]+)=([^&#]*)/ig;
            while (e = re.exec(st))
            {
                o[e[1]] = e[2];
            }
            //console.log(o);
            return o;
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

This will return an *object* of **all values** under `QS` and `hash`

*(if the `specifiedUrl` is not defined - it will look at the browser url)*

**Usages 1**: (for **specific** URL) :

`console.log($.getQs('www.example.com?ferko=suska&ee=huu#a=1&b=2&c=3'));`

this will return

`Object {ferko: "suska", ee: "huu", a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}`

**Usages 2:** (for **current** URL) :

my current URL :

`http://localhost:55643/WebSite2/HTMLPage.htm?ferko=suska&ee=huu#a=1&b=2&c=3`

so `$.getQs()`

also yields

`Object {ferko: "suska", ee: "huu", a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}`

So where is the problem ?

here it is :

`http://localhost:55643/WebSite2/HTMLPage.htm?ferko=suska&ee=huu#a=1&b=2&c=3&ee=grrr`

notice also QS has `ee` and also `hash` side has `ee`.

HOw can I reflect that in my object?

## edit

This is how i ' m reading the facebook desired value

`console.log($.getQs('http://localhost:55643/WebSite2/HTMLPage2.htm#access_token=CAACSIC6KoeroHXCK8ZD&expires_in=5439').access_token);`

yields

`CAACSIC6KoeroHXCK8ZD`

Comment: I think there is more to it, what if you have the same key twice in QS only? I find this quite common when you want to represent arrays

Comment: To be constructive I would separate QS and hash in 2 different parse functions if you cannot decide which rule should be used for merge: cumulate or overwrite. do you find me pertinent?

Comment: @alexb _same key twice in QS_ is not valid and if someone does it  , he shouldn't

Comment: There is no spec on **[this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4)** so I guess depends where you are going to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
    $.getQs = function (specificUrl) {

        function parseToObj(str, re) {
          var o = {};
          while(e = re.exec(str))
            o[e[1]] = e[2];
          return o;
        }

        var st = specificUrl || window.location.href;

        return {
          beforeHash: parseToObj(st, /([^#?&=]+)=([^&#]*)(?=.*?\#)/ig),
          afterHash: parseToObj(st, /([^#?&=]+)=([^&#]*)(?!.*?\#)/ig)
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

or better solution:

```
(function ($) {
    $.getQs = function (specificUrl) {

        function parseToObj(str, re) {
          var o = {};
          while(e = re.exec(str))
            o[e[1]] = e[2];
          return o;
        }

        var st = specificUrl || window.location.href;
        var hashPos = st.indexOf('#');
        if(hashPos == -1) hashPos = st.length;

        return {
          beforeHash: parseToObj(st.substring(0, hashPos), /([^#?&=]+)=([^&#]*)/ig),
          afterHash: parseToObj(st.substring(hashPos), /([^#?&=]+)=([^&#]*)/ig)
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```